# Loading shared libraries with ssh framework

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ssh, g++

Hi there I'am using sshxcute framework to access a Linux server. The idea is to execute an application compiled with gcc from a java project. This gcc applications has the next dependency:

```
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000300ca00000)
libocci.so.11.1 => /e01/demov7/lib/libocci.so.11.1 (0x00002ac507b33000)
libclntsh.so.11.1 => /u01/app/oracle/product/11gR2/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0x00002ac507e2e000)
libnnz11.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11gR2/lib/libnnz11.so (0x00002ac50a459000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000301ec00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000300c600000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000301ac00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000300c200000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000300be00000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000300ce00000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x000000300fa00000)
libaio.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x0000003a92800000)
```

But when I try to execute my application I have the next error

> error while loading shared libraries: libocci.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Do I need to execute somme command or configure some environment variables to allow access to the server libraries ?

I attached my code here.

```
SSHExec ssh = null;
ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("127.0.0.1", "user", "password");
ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);

CustomTask ct1 = new ExecCommand("./myapplication");
ssh.connect();           

Result res = ssh.exec(ct1);

if (res.isSuccess) {
    response = res.sysout;
} else {
    response = res.error_msg;
}
            ssh.disconnect() ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.bashrc` file and setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` variables with the path of the shared libraries the execution with ssh worked perfectly ! All the dependencies with shared libraries were solved. Thanks to larsmans

Comment: For me, it worked after adding
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ohpc/pub/mpi/openmpi3-gnu8/3.1.4/lib:/opt/ohpc/pub/compiler/gcc/8.3.0/lib64` in `.bash_profile` file and executing `source .bash_profile`.  The same doesn't work if it was `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the custom library dirs, e.g.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/e01/demov7/lib:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gR2/lib
```

Comment: @smeerkahoven: `.bash_profile` is only read by a login shell. Try putting it in `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: excelent ! I read differences between these two files. Thanks so much. I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH variables and works. Although with ps -fu the process doesn't show but with ps fux worked !!